# Python numpy matrix inverse gives incorrect values

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, inverse

What I am getting:

```
>>> Pp
matrix([[ 0.01011  ,  0.0050535,  0.0010005],
        [ 0.0050535,  0.002526 ,  0.0005001],
        [ 0.0010005,  0.0005001,  0.0001   ]])
>>> Pp.I
matrix([[  4.73894021e+17,  -9.47740572e+17,  -1.65931645e+15],
        [ -9.47740572e+17,   1.89538621e+18,   3.31846669e+15],
        [ -1.65931645e+15,   3.31846669e+15,   5.81001542e+12]])
```

What I think I should be getting:

```
matrix([[ -1.11110667e+09,   2.22220000e+09,   3.40000000e+06],
        [  2.22220000e+09,  -4.44433334e+09,  -7.00000001e+06],
        [  3.40000000e+06,  -7.00000001e+06,   1.00000000e+06]])
```

Am I using the inverse incorrectly?

By the way, this is incorrect, too:

```
>>> np.linalg.inv(Pp)
matrix([[  4.73894021e+17,  -9.47740572e+17,  -1.65931645e+15],
        [ -9.47740572e+17,   1.89538621e+18,   3.31846669e+15],
        [ -1.65931645e+15,   3.31846669e+15,   5.81001542e+12]])
```

I saw another post about this, but it had no clear solution.

Comment: Multiplying with what I think is the correct inverse:

[[1.00000000867928, 0.000000036475688, 0.000000000019985]
[0.000000003684588, 1.00000001835584, 0.000000000009159]
[0.000000000829513, 0.00000000338152, 1.00000000000165]]

Comment: Multiplying with the inverse that Pp.I gives:

[[1425599774.99986, -2844761654.99971, -4971157.28804637]
[926094855.000069, -1848950331.00014, -3232423.45800024]
[-23691699.8982929, 48003999.7965857, 84985.9995117466]

Comment: I tried it and it gives me the correct inverse.

Comment: Are you using NumPy's `matrix` type?

Comment: >>> type(Pp)
<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>

Answer (score 1):

With a simple copy-n-paste I get the correct value - both ways:

```
In [82]: [[ 0.01011  ,  0.0050535,  0.0010005], 
    ...:         [ 0.0050535,  0.002526 ,  0.0005001], 
    ...:         [ 0.0010005,  0.0005001,  0.0001   ]]                                                    
Out[82]: 
[[0.01011, 0.0050535, 0.0010005],
 [0.0050535, 0.002526, 0.0005001],
 [0.0010005, 0.0005001, 0.0001]]
In [83]: np.linalg.inv(_)                                                                                 
Out[83]: 
array([[-1.11110667e+09,  2.22220000e+09,  3.40000000e+06],
       [ 2.22220000e+09, -4.44433333e+09, -7.00000000e+06],
       [ 3.40000000e+06, -7.00000000e+06,  1.00000000e+06]])
In [84]: mm = np.matrix(_82)                                                                              
In [85]: mm.I                                                                                             
Out[85]: 
matrix([[-1.11110667e+09,  2.22220000e+09,  3.40000000e+06],
        [ 2.22220000e+09, -4.44433333e+09, -7.00000000e+06],
        [ 3.40000000e+06, -7.00000000e+06,  1.00000000e+06]])
```

Try your `Pp` in a clean session; something's wrong your session.  Or the `Pp` you show isn't the one that you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

First look at the determinant of the matrix  with `np.linalg.det(m)`. The result is `-2.249999999256419e-18` which is close to 0. 
 In theory you could say that this matrix is invertible, but because of the high condition number (use `np.linalg.cond(m)`) you might get very bad results.
Try constructing your matrix like this:

```
m = np.matrix([[ 0.01011  ,  0.0050535,  0.0010005],
        [ 0.0050535,  0.002526 ,  0.0005001],
        [ 0.0010005,  0.0005001,  0.0001   ]], dtype=np.float64)
```

This indeed will get better results for `m.I`:

```
matrix([[-1.11110667e+09,  2.22220000e+09,  3.40000000e+06],
        [ 2.22220000e+09, -4.44433333e+09, -7.00000000e+06],
        [ 3.40000000e+06, -7.00000000e+06,  1.00000000e+06]])
```

Checking results with `m * m.I`:

```
matrix([[ 1.00000000e+00,  8.19379276e-10,  6.10730759e-12],
        [-1.18821050e-10,  1.00000000e+00,  3.87522234e-12],
        [ 1.48254137e-11, -6.72848576e-11,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: thanks, this helped to understand, so what if the determinant is close to zero, how to force np in such case to still invert and produce the correct values

Answer (score 0):

I made a goof in defining the matrix.

I defined it as such:

```
Pp=np.matrix([(x11,x12,x13),(x21,x22,x23),(x31,x32,x33)])
```

instead of the correct way, which is:

```
Pp=np.matrix([[x11,x12,x13],[x21,x22,x23],[x31,x32,x33]])
```

Interesting that everything pretty much worked correctly except the inverse.